# Parse check if user already tapped button

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to implement a like feature in my app using parse. If a user taps the vote up button. The label increases changing the like number in parse side as well. However with my code a user can tap many times to increase the like. I would like to make it detect that user has tapped and make the like button disabled. To do that I have made a class in parse called "Liked".  I made a username, imageId both a string column and a likeStatus as a Boolean . However I can't make is so that if a user likes any image it will add new item to it with userId, ImageId and likeStatus.
This is the Collection View code

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("newview", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell
        let item = self.votes[indexPath.row]
        // Display the country name

        if let value = item["imageText"] as? String {
            cell.postsLabel.text = value
        }

        // Display "initial" flag image
        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
        cell.postsImageView.image = initialThumbnail

        cell.complition = {
            self.likeButton(indexPath)
        }

        if let votesValue = item["votes"] as? Int
        {
            cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votesValue)"
        }

        // Fetch final flag image - if it exists
        if let value = item["imageFile"] as? PFFile {

            cell.postsImageView.file = value
            cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    cell.postsImageView.image = image
                }
            })
        }
        return cell
    }


    /*
    ==========================================================================================
    Segue methods
    ==========================================================================================
    */

    func likeButton(indexPath:NSIndexPath)
    {
        let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell

        let object = self.votes[indexPath.row]

        if let likes = object["votes"] as? Int
        {
            object["votes"] = likes + 1
            object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{ (success:Bool,error:NSError?) -> Void in
                println("Data saved")

            }
            cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(likes + 1)"
                    }
        else
        {
            object["votes"] = 1
            object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{ (success:Bool,error:NSError?) -> Void in
                println("Data saved")
            }
            cell.votesLabel?.text = "1"
        }

    }
```

and this is the cell code

```
@IBAction func vote(sender: AnyObject) {

    if self.complition != nil
    {
        self.complition!()
    }
}
}
```

Any tips or How am I able to do this in code?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was by using a class in Parse that I called "UserLikeActivity" or something to that effect, and in it, it had a column pointer to the user that did the liking, a pointer to the actitivy that was liked (in my case it was a post), a type (indicating whether it was an upvote, downvote, follow, etc), and a pointer to the user who created the activity that was liked.

Now, when I was querying Parse to set my tables up, not only did I query the class that contained all the posts, but I also queried this class, which I then saved and used to determine the button state. So for every cell, if the activity had already been liked, I disabled the button. Hopefully this will help you get going in the right direction since you've asked this question about 7 times.